# how to populate main table with values from child tables

Tags: c#, mysql

```
    Id | Product Name |Color | Material
    ------------------------------------    // products
    1          car    1      | 2
    2          desk   3      | 1
    3          window 2      | 3


    -----------------------
    Id | Product Color Name 
    -----------------------    // productColor
    1          red
    2          blue
    3          yellow


    -----------------------
    Id | Product Material Name 
    -----------------------    // productMaterial
    1          Metal
    2          Glass
    3          Wood

    -----------------------
```

I have a dropdownlist that reads from table Products and populate textboxes with specified property of material.
I use foreignKey to connect products table with data from Material and colors.
How can I populate the database with new products. ( the new products have  and new materials)

New Product that will be listed in ddlist  will be named phone and populates txtboxes using color(purple) and material (plastic)

Comment: You can joint two tables and get list. Look at join master detail tables,

Comment: How these two tables are connected? I mean by which key?

Comment: The items in product table will be entered by user, and they are different.

Comment: the table uses fk_id_material  referenced to db.tablename(materials) using column Id MaterialsName referenced by MaterialsId

Comment: @Anand I`ve edited my post:)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have Product as your main table which has a foreign key to hold the material ID.

In this case, to retrieve the material of a selected product, you can use a join and get material name.

How to insert new products with matrial depends on your overall design.

Say you have a screen with a text box, to take input for product. You allow user to enter product name and save that in your product table. On the screen where user is supposed to enter material, first make him select a product. Then save these two entries in two tables.

If you want both to be added in one go, fire two insert queries; first on material; get its ID as output; then in product table, where you now have material ID.

Hope that helps.

*One more thing; you don't have a product ID in color table.*